# How do I change the view in Midnight Commander?

Tags: midnight-commander

I have been using Midnight Commander for a while and I have always been able to view the contents of a directory in each panel. I made some change that now the left panel shows the contents of the file highlighted in the right panel. How do I change this back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click/Select the "Left" menu item, then select "List...".

Or with keyboard only: Press <kbd>F9</kbd> -> <kbd>L</kbd> -> <kbd>L</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I had clicked that but looking at the next dialog I thought that the correct listing mode was already selected so I didn't click OK. This time I did!

Comment: @Liam great! =D Would you mind selecting this answer as accepted if it worked out for you? =)

Comment: begging for karma bumps puts you on the dark side. Shame.

Comment: @vtest I'm always pushing fairly new users to accept answers for solved questions ;) Not just my own... I don't mind the rep I get from it... And I also wonder how much 15 points of rep would bump up my 5100 rep status... So please don't judge that easily just because I voted down your answer.

Comment: gladly, I couldn't in the first 15 minutes though :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to revert most Linux apps to default settings is to delete/rename their user-specific settings directory and restart them. For mc that would be **~/.mc**

Comment: Bit overkill for this one don't you think? -1